# How can I toggle mobile data on/off on my Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, mobile-data

How can I toggle mobile data on/off on my Samsung Galaxy S5 (running Lollipop) without having to unlock the device?

Comment: Is your device rooted? @newbuddy2015

Comment: Do you want to toggle that manually – or shall it be toggled automatically on certain conditions (e.g. location, time)?

Comment: Lollipop allows you to access quick-settings without unlocking the screen. Your mobile data widget possibly would be there. Can you not access it by sliding down the quick-setting bar?

Comment: @Lucky my device is not rooted. I would want if there is any tweaks in samsung s5 factory settings

Comment: @Izzy I would only want to toggle manually.. just like when the device is unlocked by sliding down the quick setting bar.

Comment: @Firelord when is device is locked by a password, i couldn't swipe down for quick-settings whereas when the device password is not set i could do the same. May be it is the way samsung has implemented. Need to know if there is a workaround for this...

Comment: @Firelord Even if we can drag the notification bar when locked down the notification quick settings doesnot have toggling of mobile data..only way is to go to the settings by clicking the gear icon at the top near the user icon..[Notification_bar_Icons_Screenshot](http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/145202-image/Battery-percentage-is-now-displayed-in-the-Quick-Settings-menu.jpg)

Comment: @newbuddy2015 the Power Toggles app recently added toggling of Mobile data in Lollipop version recently but that is only supported on rooted devices. But Wifi on/off is supported when the device is locked.

Comment: @Lucky that's the problem with "newer versions" of Android (restricting what apps are allowed to toggle) – I've lost track on what was removed with which version. // newbuddy: Might be possible e.g. with Tasker (or some other automation tool). With Tasker, you could e.g. assing a specific "shake-pattern" to toggle mobile data. Didn't try that myself yet – but unless your Android version doesn't allow that at all, it should be possible without root (otherwise with root).